# App crashed after registering dependency service in app delegate with maui

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-7.0

While migrating Xamarin.Forms to .NET Maui targeting .NET 7, I have registered dependency services with FinishedLaunching method in `appdelegate.cs` But while performing `HttpClient.GetAsync()`, the app crashes.

If I remove the registration code, then `HttpCient.GetAsync()` is working fine, but I get a runtime error about the dependency service methods. How to resolve the issue?

```
DependencyService.Register<IWorkService, WorkService>();
DependencyService.Register<ISalesService, SalesService>();
```

Eventhough `HttpCient.GetAsync()` is under try-catch it is not catching the exception or httprequestexception. It is throwing `nullreferenceexception` in UIApplication.Main

Comment: What is the exception you're getting? Message, stacktrace, properties.

Comment: Apart from the missing exception, seeing the actual code where it crashes would be useful as well. MAUI comes with DI built-in so you don't need to use the DependencyService anymore. This line also looks suspicious: `DependencyService.Register<IWorkService, AppDelegate>()` - it seems that your `AppDelegate` implements the `IWorkService` interface, which violates the Single Responsibility Principle. You may want to reconsider this.

Comment: Exception details added

Answer (score 0):

About using dependency service in MAUI, you can refer to [davidbritch's comment](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/187#issuecomment-951048271):

> `DependencyService` will eventually work, purely to provide an easy
> upgrade path for Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. However, it won't be the
> optimal way to invoke code on a platform.
>
> The .NET MAUI approach is to use partial classes. The idea is that in
> your cross-platform code you'd call `GetString`, and place your platform
> implementations as partial classes in the **Platforms > Android**,
> **Platform > iOS** (etc.) folders. Multi-targeting will then take care of
> the rest (only compiling the iOS GetString method for iOS, the Android
> GetString method for Android etc.).

And here is the [code sample](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/files/7424782/MauiApp3.zip).

In addition, you can also check the answer this case: [MAUI: DependencyService.Get() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74236424/19902734).